# converting data to quoted words to escape special characters

Tags: perl

In my Perl program, I am fetching an encrypted email, decoding it and processing it further. I am facing a problem since the data contains: `%localappdata%`
I could not use the qw() function directly since the data is being fetched from the mailbox. Is there a way to apply this function?
How do I use it so that special characters are not recognized as special characters but normal characters? Or is there a regex to do so?

Update: The *processing* that I am doing is converting the data to HTML and sending it to REST API using Curl.

Update 2: Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/8cd801fedeb90a5ca7fc
`$description` contains `%localappdata%`

Comment: what are you trying to do? If the data is stored inside a scalar, no special characters will be converted. `qw` is used for turning a string of characters in your source code into a list of strings.

Comment: After decoding the email, I am sending the data to REST API.
I want the % character not to be recognized as a special character. The data is stored in scalar variable. What is the other variable type that would be appropriate in this case?

Comment: Your question is unfathomable. I don't understand why it is a problem that the data contains `%localappdata%`, or how `qw//` could help you. Is the decryption failing somehow? Or are you perhaps trying to split the message on whitespace like `qw//` does with string literals?

Comment: I am not able to process the data because I think perl is recognizing the % character in %localappdata% as a special character. I thought qw// or a regex would help me in this case?
I am able to process the data that does not have % character.

Comment: @rad: Please describe what processing you are doing. Are you putting the contents of the message inside double quotes? If so then it is very likely to fix your problem if you remove the quotes. Otherwise `quotemeta` may help you, but these are wild guesses unless you show your code.

Comment: Please refer to my updates in the question. The content is not in double quotes. How would quotemeta help me?

Comment: What you are trying to do in "Clean the body - l. 32" should be done by an external module (->quotemeta) to guarantee everything is handled correctly. This has **nothing** to do with double quotes.

Comment: @rad: I have added a solution now that I have seen what your program is doing. Please take a look and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK thank you for showing your complete code. The problem is that you are passing the contents of `$body` as a URL parameter, and so the HTTP protocl needs various characters escaping to pass them through properly.

You can achieve this with the [`URI::Escape`](https://metacpan.org/module/URI%3a%3aEscape) module, and you will no longer have to do the sanitizing that you do on line 125 and the lines following `# clean the body`.

This program uses a string containing all the problem characters you have identified, and translates it using the module. If you use `uri_escape` on the contents of `$body` before appending it to the URL for Curl then everything should work.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI::Escape 'uri_escape';

my $body = '%localappdata% â & ';

print uri_escape $body;
```

**output**

```
%25localappdata%25%20%E2%20%26%20
```

---

**Update**

For manipulating URLs in general it is best to use the [`URI` module](https://metacpan.org/module/URI) which will do all necessary escaping for you in both the path and the query part of the URL.

The program below shows how to generate the URL you need to pass to `$curl->setopt` using this method

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use URI;

my $url = URI->new('https://this/is/the/url');
my $body = '%localappdata% â & ';

$url->query_form(body => $body);
print $url, "\n";
```

**output**

```
https://this/is/the/url?body=%25localappdata%25+%E2+%26+
```

(Note that this method uses `+` instead of `%20` for space characters. Either is acceptable in the query portion of a URL.)

This URL can be set as a Curl option directly by writing

```
$curl->setopt(CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough, Borodin! Let me know when you come to NYC!

Answer (score -1):

To escape something use a regexp to process your data:

```
my $email = "To: foo@example.com\n\nHi Rad,\nI just opened %appdata% and...";
$email =~ s/ % /\\%/xg; # escapes all percent signs
```

This would replace `%appdata%` with `\%appdata\%`. I don't know how you API likes its input data, adjust accordingly.

EDIT: You put the scalar $description into a URL (Git line 30 and 41)! Percent-signs are the escape character there! so just do `s/%/%%/g` on any data you put into any url and be happy everafter :)

Comment: The `/x` modifier applies to the *regular expression* and not to the replacement string. Your code will change `%appdata%` to ` \% appdata \% `. (Hmm. Looks like backtick markdown doesn't like leading spaces :( ).

Comment: I am sorry. It dint go through.

Comment: @amon: that isn't how you escape percent signs in URLs. `%%localdata%%` is an invalid value and you want `%25localdata%25` instead (`ord('%')` being 0x25).